# Bootstrap + form group inside a form horizontal giving a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest bootstrap.

I have a form (`class="form-horizontal"`) and inside I am adding a div with the class "form-group", and the result gives a horizontal scroll bar.

I have created an example in JSfiddle using the same code from Bootstrap website.
You can see it here better:
  http://jsfiddle.net/SergioKastro/q4pq08rc/

How do I stop showing the horizontal scroll bar?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your code inside a `<div class="container">` or `<div class="container-fluid">`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Everything inside your body should be enclosed inside a `<div class="container">` or `<div class="container-fluid">`.

`"container"` has a fixed width depending on your screen size while `"container-fluid"` scales directly with the width of the browser.

Comment: Perfect, it works. I should have posted my question much earlier. Thank you

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as solved to show other that your question doesn't need more attention. You may upvote my answer too, if you liked it ;)

Comment: Any idea, why this happens? I tried to inspect the elements in my browser. The size of the `form-horizontal` is about **30-40px** smaller than the size of `form-group`, although the former contains the latter. **This is what creates the scrollbar.** By adding `container`, the size of `form-group` is limited to the size of the `container`, but the size of `form-horizontal` is still about 30-40px smaller. **Is this is a bug or a feature? Will it be fixed in the future?**